# Color Cycle Xcode UIView background

Tags: xcode, uiview, colors, background-color, cycle

Im just a newbie so not sure if this is the correct place to ask.

I found this code on your site to make an xcode iphone app where the background color cycles - [UIView backgroundColor color cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241655/uiview-backgroundcolor-color-cycle/6241680)

and it works great! How could I tweak it so it just cycles through once and ends on the last colour in the array?

Thank you for you help.

```
//  ViewController.m
//  colorCycle

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self doBackgroundColorAnimation];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) doBackgroundColorAnimation {
    static NSInteger i = 0;
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];

    if(i >= [colors count]) {
        i = 0;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ++i;
        [self doBackgroundColorAnimation];
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a `return` statement in the if block.

```
- (void) doBackgroundColorAnimation {
static NSInteger i = 0;
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];

if(i >= [colors count]) {
    return;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    ++i;
    [self doBackgroundColorAnimation];
}];
```

}